# Building Phoenix Storage Handler - finding hbase.compat.version and hbase-thirdparty-version params

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to creating the bin file to connect Apache Hive to Apache Phoenix.
I'm following the documentation provided here:
https://phoenix.apache.org/hive_storage_handler.html

I'm on the "Building" phase, and there's a command provided at some time:

```
mvn clean package -Dhbase.version=2.1.10 -Dhbase.compat.version=2.1.6 -Dhadoop.version=3.0.3 -Dzookeeper.version=3.4.10 -Dhbase-thirdparty-version=2.1.0
```

All good, but I don't where I can find the following params:

**hbase.compat.version**

**hbase-thirdparty-version**

Could someone please help me?

Here are the current Hadoop components versions I'm using:

Hadoop: 3.3.6

Zookeeper: 3.8.6

HBase: 2.5.6

So my current command at the moment is:

```
mvn clean package -Dhbase.version=2.5.6 -Dhbase.compat.version=2.4.1 -Dhadoop.version=3.3.6 -Dzookeeper.version=3.8.3 -Dhbase-thirdparty-version=2.1.0
```

But honnestly I have no idea if this makes sense, I just surfed on maven repo but I'm not sure about this, because I believe this are params the could be defined somewhere, but I don't now where.

Thanks everyone for your help!